# extend element height by sliding (as opposed to abruptly expanding)

Tags: jquery

i would like to expand the height of the box when it is clicked on.

```
 $(this).find("textarea").css("height","2.6em").focus();
```

The code above expands the box, but does so abruptly.

How can i make it do so in a sliding manner that is much more elegant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) instead of [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/), like this:

```
$(this).find("textarea").animate({ height: "2.6em" }).focus();
```

Some browsers lose the focus on animation though, I recall from a question a few weeks back, you may need to do this instead:

```
$(this).find("textarea").animate({ height: "2.6em" }, function() {
  $(this).focus();
})
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! One side effect of this is that the effect still continues to happen, even when it is already in focus. how do i cancel the effect when it is in focus? =)

Comment: @ming - I'm not sure what context this is inside of, where is this code running?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at jQuery's [animate function](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

```
$(this).find("textarea").animate({
    height: "2.6em"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`size`](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Size) effect will do this smoothly. `Animate`, also.

```
$(this).find("textarea").effect("size", { to: {height: 2.6em} }, 1000).focus();;
```